# Javascript function does not work on mobile but works on pc

Tags: javascript

I have got a dynamic categories list, the list gets printed on the page with checkboxes. I want to select the categories and print the products associated to those categories with AJAX. My function works on PC, but when I try this on mobile it does not work. Am I using a function that only works on PC?

```
var CategorieIds =
            [<?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE Actief = '1'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo('"'.$row["ID"].'",');
                }
            }

            ?>"000"]

        var EnabledCategorieIDs =  []


        CategorieIds.forEach(SetCatList)
        if(EnabledCategorieIDs.length > 0){
            var URL = JSON.stringify(EnabledCategorieIDs)
        }else{
            var URL = JSON.stringify(CategorieIds)
        }

        console.log(URL)
        GetProduct(URL)

        function SetCatList(value, index, array){
            if(value != "000"){
                var checkBox = document.getElementById("Check"+value);
                if(checkBox.checked == true){
                    EnabledCategorieIDs.push(value)
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Kind regards

Comment: are you sure this is not a php issue?

Comment: @ZimriLeijen Yes, if I use the chrome console I can see that the SetCatList does not update EnabledCategorieId's, so it is a javascript issue. But the weird thing is that it works on desktop.

Comment: is `SetCatList` call? ere can't you use console.log to check what's receiving?

Comment: @PabloCG I am using the console.log to check what it is receiving, and it works when I am on PC, but when I try it on mobile, the console gives me an empty list, so my guess is that the document.getElementById is doing something weird and not receiving the correct values

Comment: If you are using Chrome or Safari on both devices you may try USB debugging to figure out what is happening on the device

Comment: @Francesco I am using the mobile emulator in the chrome browser, so I can see the console

Comment: @PietHendri if you think that's the problem, print the `checkbox` content and see what it shows.  I'd check first what `CategorieIds ` have before calling.

Comment: @PabloCG the document.getElementById is not returning the correct value of the checkbox, I checked it but if I log if the checkbox is checked it returns false, but the Id's are correct.

Comment: what does `document.getElementById("Check"+value)` returns? @PietHendri